# ERROR: Connection[106]: Reading failed: End of input

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, realm

I have app which has a real time chat module. Its uses Nodejs and Socket.io plus the front end uses Realm to send and get messages. The whole backend is on PHP but Nodejs is only for real time chat and connection with realm. Nodejs script take the data from Realm and insert it to Mysql DB which connected to PHP backend as well.

The problems is that sometimes the live chat stops working and no user can communicate. I seriously don't know where exactly the issue is I am not able to detect the issue yet. However server throw these logs using pm2:

```
0|index    | ERROR: Connection[214]: Reading failed: End of input
0|index    | ERROR: Connection[106]: Reading failed: End of input
```

And sometimes this:

```
0|index    | {"type":"https://docs.realm.io/server/troubleshoot/errors#service-unavailable","title":"The requested service is temporarily unavailable.","status":503,"code":802}
0|index    | ERROR: Connection[259]: Websocket: Expected HTTP response 101 Switching Protocols, but received:
0|index    | HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
0|index    | Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
0|index    | Connection: keep-alive
0|index    | Content-Length: 163
0|index    | Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
0|index    | Date: Tue, 20 Aug 2019 06:42:16 GMT
0|index    | ETag: W/"a3-rTk0VRApT9JjCEic5u7MEh0oBX4"
0|index    | Server: nginx/1.15.5
0|index    | X-Powered-By: Express
```

And sometimes this as well:

```
0|index    | {"type":"https://docs.realm.io/server/troubleshoot/errors#service-unavailable","title":"The requested service is temporarily unavailable.","status":503,"code":802}
0|index    | Unhandled session token refresh error for user 4049724eab9cc72e53943afb6ead4cd6 at path /var/www/nodejs/simpill-node-running-live/realm-object-server/listener/realms/94d68cdc4ade184b3e6ecd21701b2acf/__permission/{8d3114393c09a1f0-ccc239e8c3bdbc4d}.realm { Error: The requested service is temporarily unavailable.
0|index    |     at new AuthError (/var/www/nodejs/simpill-node-running-live/node_modules/realm/lib/errors.js:22:25)
0|index    |     at validateRefresh (/var/www/nodejs/simpill-node-running-live/node_modules/realm/lib/user-methods.js:201:21)
0|index    |     at performFetch.then.then (/var/www/nodejs/simpill-node-running-live/node_modules/realm/lib/user-methods.js:307:29)
0|index    |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
0|index    |   name: 'AuthError',
0|index    |   message: 'The requested service is temporarily unavailable.',
0|index    |   stack:
0|index    |    'Error: The requested service is temporarily unavailable.\n    at new AuthError (/var/www/nodejs/simpill-node-running-live/node_modules/realm/lib/errors.js:22:25)\n    at validateRefresh (/var/www/nodejs/simpill-node-running-live/node_modules/realm/lib/user-methods.js:201:21)\n    at performFetch.then.then (/var/www/nodejs/simpill-node-running-live/node_modules/realm/lib/user-methods.js:307:29)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)'
```

When I searched about the first error it give me this issue created on realm github:
https://github.com/realm/realm-object-server/issues/100

But I couldn't find any help from this issue as well

And the third error give me this issue:

https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1116

But same here as well nothing helpful.

As far as I think all the issues are related to Realm connection with Nodejs. The company is using realm cloud database.

I want an expert to help me in this please. Someone who knows realm well enough because I am pretty new to it. Please let me know if you need any further info.

Node Version: 10.13.0
Realm Npm Module: 2.20.0

Comment: I have the exact same issue(s). Did you get any help yet?